# a closed, convex nonempty subset of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

If $E$ is a Banach space, and $F$ is a nonzero continuous linear functional on $E$.

Let $M =\{ x \in E: F(x)=1 \}$. I was able to prove that $M$ is closed, convex and nonempty, but the second part asks to show that

1. $\inf_{x \in M} ||x||=\frac{1}{||F||}$.
2. If $F$ does not attain its norm on $E$ then there is no closest point to the origin in $M$. (i.e. the infimum in (1) is not attained).

My work:
I have $|F(x)| \leq ||F||||x||$ for all $x\in E$, so this holds for all $x \in M$ this implies that $1 \leq ||F||||x||$, i.e. $\frac{1}{||F||} \leq ||x||$ for all $x \in M$ so we pass the infimum to get

$\frac{1}{||F||} \leq \inf_{x \in M}||x||$. For the other direction, I apply the definition

$||F|| = \sup_{0\ne x \in E}{\frac{|F(x)|}{||x||}}$
but the right hand side is greater than or equal to $\sup_{x \in M}{\frac{|F(x)|}{||x||}}=\sup_{x \in M}{\frac{1}{||x||}}$, but this did not help me to get the other direction.
I am not sure if this wrong argument to prove (1) or I miss something. I would appreciate any help and hint for this and to prove 2.

Comment: The trick is to consider $x/F(x)$ which is in $M$, unless $x\in\ker F$.

Comment: @Berci I still couldn't see how this element can help me here. I see it is in $M$ but not sure to which inequality above I should apply this element to get the other direction.

Comment: For (2), if the infimum is attained at $x_0\in M$ then $||F||=1/||x_0||=F(x_0)/||x_0||=F(x_0/||x_0||)$ which is impossible since F does not attain its norm